# I am using google colab, everything is up to date and still get this error TypeError: drop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using google colab, everything is up to date and still get this error TypeError: drop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'. What am I doing wrong? The error is coming from the last two lines of code. If I get my data using pandas dataframe from an array, it works fine. Here's the error output.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import io

from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

admissions = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['student_data.csv']))


# Make Dummy variables for rank
data = pd.concat([admissions, pd.get_dummies(admissions['rank'], prefix='rank')], axis=1)

# Drop the column in which the dummy variables was created from
data.pop('rank')

# Standardize features
for field in ['gre', 'gpa']:
    # get the mean and standard deviations
    mean, std = data[field].mean(), data[field].std()
    
    # get the ...
    data.loc[:,field] = (data[field] -mean) / std
    
# split the random 10% of the data for testing
np.random.seed(42)

# takes away 90% data, test_data = data.index[sample], data.drop(sample) # removes the 90% and stores the remaining 10% into test_data
sample = np.random.choice(data.index, size=int(len(data)*0.9), replace=False) 

# Split into features and targets
features, targets = data.drop('admit', axis=1), data['admit'] # takes the admit column away and store the remaining in the features and the # admin in the targets
features_test, targets_test = test_data.drop('admit', axis=1), test_data['admit']
```

Here's the error ouput

```
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-1-9293df238858> in <module>()
     31 
     32 # Split into features and targets
---> 33 features, targets = data.drop('admit', axis=1), data['admit'] # takes the admit column away and store the remaining in the features and the # admin in the targets
     34 features_test, targets_test = test_data.drop('admit', axis=1), test_data['admit']

TypeError: drop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

Comment: Can you check `type(data)` before calling `drop` and `pd.__version__`. I'm not able to reproduce your error with any recent pandas version. Even `pd.Series.drop` accepts the `axis` keyword.

Comment: The data type is <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a `pandas` question, and it has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `deep-learning` - kindly use the appropriate tags and not irrelevant ones (edited).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this alternative?

```py
data.drop(columns=['admit'])
```

In general, this should return the same thing as yours. But from times to times when I got the same errors, this works.

Comment: It didn't work. It brought out similar error. TypeError: drop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'

Answer (score 0):

I try to reproduce your code this way in Colab:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
admissions = pd.DataFrame({"gre": [5,6,5,1,21,5,8], 
                          "gpa": [1,2,2,2,3,1,4], 
                          "rank": ['a','a','b','c','a','b','a'],
                           "admit": [0,1,1,1,0,1,1]})
test_data = pd.DataFrame({"gre": [5,6,5], 
                          "gpa": [3,1,4], 
                          "rank": ['a','b','a'],
                           "admit": [0,1,1]})
```

Then copy your code from `# Make Dummy variables for rank` until the end. It produces no error. I would suggest you to add `print(data.head())` before the `# Split into features and targets` to see how does the `data` look like. In my case, this code

```py
print(data)
# Split into features and targets
features, targets = data.drop('admit', axis=1), data['admit'] # takes the admit column away and store the remaining in the features and the # admin in the targets
features_test, targets_test = test_data.drop('admit', axis=1), test_data['admit']
print(features)
print(targets)
```

produces output like this:

```py
        gre       gpa  admit  rank_a  rank_b  rank_c
0 -0.357384 -1.069045      0       1       0       0
1 -0.201028 -0.133631      1       1       0       0
2 -0.357384 -0.133631      1       0       1       0
3 -0.982806 -0.133631      1       0       0       1
4  2.144304  0.801784      0       1       0       0
5 -0.357384 -1.069045      1       0       1       0
6  0.111682  1.737198      1       1       0       0
        gre       gpa  rank_a  rank_b  rank_c
0 -0.357384 -1.069045       1       0       0
1 -0.201028 -0.133631       1       0       0
2 -0.357384 -0.133631       0       1       0
3 -0.982806 -0.133631       0       0       1
4  2.144304  0.801784       1       0       0
5 -0.357384 -1.069045       0       1       0
6  0.111682  1.737198       1       0       0
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    0
5    1
6    1
```